# zend2 doctrine 2 form intgergration OneToOne

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I  am trying to integrate **Doctrine 2 to my Zend 2**. I wish to join two entities on my form; i.e ONeToOne.

I followed the [tutorial by  gammamatrix](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#a-complete-example-using-zendform).

I was able to successfully integrate doctrine and was able to Hydrate one of the entities.

The problem occurs when I try to join the second entity fieldset to the first entity. I keep getting the following fatal error message:

> **Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Workers\Form\Fieldset\WorkerAddressFieldset::__construct() must
>   implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, none
>   given,**

I will start with the fieldsets and show you how I tried to pass the ObjectManager to both fieldsets.

The first fieldset: AboutYou (This is the owner in the relationship);

I pass the ObjectManager through the form on the controller page:

```
$form = new CreateAboutYouForm($this->getEntityManager());
```

The first part of the below code works alone. i.e if i dont place the workeraddressfieldset into the code.

```
class AboutYouFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('AboutYou');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Workers\Entity\AboutYou'))
             ->setObject(new AboutYou()); 

$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'firstName',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'First Name',
            ),
        ));

$addressFieldset = new WorkerAddressFieldset($objectManager);
         $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Workers\Form\Fieldset\workerAddressFieldset',
            'name' => 'WorkerAddress',
            'options' => array(
                'label' =>  $addressFieldset
            )
        ));

}
```

You will notice above that I created a **workerAddressFieldset object** and attempted to pass the ObjectManager into the class that way.  But it does not seem to receive the values. I am not clear why.

The second fieldset (the workersAddress):

```
class WorkerAddressFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('WorkerAddress');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Workers\Entity\WorkerAddress'))
             ->setObject(new WorkerAddress());

}
```

I would really appreciate some advice or a working sample of how others have been able to join the fieldsets together.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you try to add the Fieldset from String. Given the fact that your `AddressFieldset` has a `__construct(ObjectManager $om)` however you first need to instantiate the Fieldset and then add it to your form. Like:

```
class AboutYouFieldset extends Fieldset 
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('about-you');

        $this->add(); // your first element

        $fieldset = new WorkerAddressFieldset($objectManager);
        $this->add($fieldset);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Sam. its great to finally communicate with you. i am very very familar with your articles: i have read most of them in detail. You really are a great inspiration to all of us.  Thanks for replying to me. i am however not clear what i need to do. can you please explain a little further.

Comment: @PaulKendal I've changed the Pseudo-Code into PHP-Code. Like this it should be clear what i meant (i hope).

Comment: Hi Sam. great. thanks. i will give it a try tonight. thanks so much.